# How can a user create an ATA in phantom wallet before owning the actual token?

Tags: token, spl, ata

So, I have a list of 20k+ whitelisted people for a project, and am trying to find a way to airdrop it without significant cost. As i understand, the biggest cost of the actual airdrop is opening ATA for all the users, is there a way for users to open it themselves in phantom wallet so they can claim my token via a tg faucet i developed without me paying for the ATA fee? Or does anyone have any other solutions to this, most bulk senders quote me around 100+ SOL for the transaction/ATA rent fees.

Thanks!